# Catch Json POST exception

Tags: c#, json, post

I have a page method:

```
[WebMethod(false)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string AMethod(string someString)
{...}
```

When I call it by `Json POST` and pass an invalid string such as: '
I get the following error:

```
{"Message":"Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected. (22): [{\u0027someString\u0027: \u00272\u0027\u0027}]","StackTrace":"
```

I wish to catch this exception on server side (C#) and not show it to the client, however this error occurs before reaching this method.

Where can I catch this exception?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing in an invalid bit of data.

```
[{'someString': \u00272''}]
```

I'm not sure what unicode unicode 00272 is but it probably shouldn't be there.

It looks like \u00272 is not valid, so you're probably sending your data as

`[{'someString': '2''}]`

which isn't valid as you need to escape the ' (this should be done by using a JSON.stringify method). If you're not using JSON.stringify it might not be sending JSON to the method - use Fiddler to check, but it may just be posting `data?like=this`.

Comment: Thanx for the response but as I said, I'm passing an invalid string on purpose, and I'm doing it from an outside application and not from my own javascript. the only thing I'm trying to find out is where can I catch this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to catch this exception in web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Home.aspx">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="Home.aspx"/>
   </customErrors> 
</system.web>
```

it solves my problem although it may not be the best solution